# How to fix Error called by redirect: "Cannot read property 'split' of undefined TypeError"

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular2-routing

I just get error called by redirect code, but I should get redirect with my code:

```
  if (!localStorage.getItem('emp_user')) {
        console.log('HELLO THERE');
        this.router.navigate(['create'])
      }
```

And also Error that I get:

> core.js:5847 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot
>   read property 'split' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'split' of undefined
>       at defaultUrlMatcher (router.js:530)
>       at match (router.js:2718)
>       at ApplyRedirects.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.ApplyRedirects.matchSegmentAgainstRoute
>   (router.js:2564)
>       at ApplyRedirects.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.ApplyRedirects.expandSegmentAgainstRoute
>   (router.js:2515)
>       at MapSubscriber.project (router.js:2488)
>       at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next
>   (map.js:35)
>       at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next
>   (Subscriber.js:53)
>       at Observable._subscribe (subscribeToArray.js:5)
>       at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe
>   (Observable.js:43)
>       at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe
>   (Observable.js:29)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:852)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:809)
>       at zone.js:913
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:423)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:24328)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:422)
>       at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
>       at drainMicroTaskQueue

UPD:
Routes

**App.routing**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  }, {
    path: '',
    component: AdminLayoutComponent,
    children: [{
      path: '',
      loadChildren: './layouts/admin-layout/admin-layout.module#AdminLayoutModule'
    },
  ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: './_user/user.module#UserModule'
  },
  // {path: '**', redirectTo: 'default/error/403', pathMatch: 'full'},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
       useHash: true
    })
  ],
  exports: [
  ],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**Admin-layout.routing**

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { DashboardComponent } from '../../dashboard/dashboard.component';

export const AdminLayoutRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'dashboard',      component: DashboardComponent },
    { component: ConfirmDialog }
];
```

**user.routing**

```
export const UserRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: UserComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: 'create',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            },
            {
                path: 'create',
                component: RegistrationComponent
            },
        ]
    }
];
```

Comment: can you show us the routerModule file

Comment: Try with this.router.navigateByUrl("/user/create") assuming your url exists

Comment: @Robertgarcia no, it's not work :(

Comment: @GhoulAhmed well, I added

Comment: The route you are trying to access doesnt looks like it exists, you have /create route, but you dont have /user/create route

Comment: Please post your code in place of screenshot

Comment: @nircraft I did

Comment: @GhoulAhmed  Not work, do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

change this path (app.routiing.ts)

```
{
   path: '',
   loadChildren: './_user/user.module#UserModule
}
```

to

```
{
   path: 'user',
   loadChildren: './_user/user.module#UserModule
}
```

Comment: yeah, in my sceen I just deleted from app.routing - User, on that moment
Can you have an one more idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined at defaultUrlMatcher
```

this happens because of `{ component: ConfirmDialog }` in `AdminLayoutRoutes`
In defaultUrlMatcher it checks the router path by splitting something like `route.path.spliter('/')`  because of an undefined path it throws an error.

it should be `{path: 'pathforcomponent', component: ConfirmDialog}`